# w images in header float issue

Tags: html, css, header, css-float

I have a header that is larger than most screen widths. I centered that and I have the overflow hidden so when you expand your browser on a bigger screen more of it is visible. I also have 2 images on top of that, one floating right and one floating left. my problem is that the left image is in place floating left but the right image won't go all the way right. both if I put both images on the same z-index they just stack instead of floating right and left. Any suggestions? here is my css and html:

```
 #triangleleft{
 width:100%;
 height:531px;
 z-index:58;
 position:absolute;
 top:+53px;
}

 #triangleright{
 width:100%;
 height:531px;
 z-index:59;
 position:absolute;
 top:+53px;
}

.triangleleft{
 background:url(Layer-58.png)no-repeat;
 float:left;
 margin-left:0px;
 height:531px;
 width:100%;
}

.triangleright{
 background:url(Layer-59.png)no-repeat;
 float:right;
 margin-right:0px;
 height:531px;
 width:100%;
}

 <div id="triangleleft">
 <div class="triangleleft"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="triangleright">
 <div class="triangleright"></div>
 </div>
```

also here is the code for my header image that I think is screwing this up

```
#wrapper {
 height:100%;
 position: relative;
}
#Layer-57 {
 position: relative;
 height:529px;
 background:#3b96a9 url(layer-57.jpg) top center no-repeat;
 top:-529px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 z-index: 57;
}

<div id="wrapper"> <div id="Layer-57"></div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your style with this

```
<style>
#triangleleft {
    width:90%;
    height: 531px;
    z-index: 58;
    position: absolute;
    top: +53px;
}
#triangleright {
    width:90%;
    height: 531px;
    z-index: 59;
    position: absolute;
    top: +53px;
}
.triangleleft {
    background: url(Layer-58.png)no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 531px;
    width: 100%;
}
.triangleright {
    background: url(Layer-59.png)no-repeat;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 531px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you can use in this way: with 90%  #triangleleft {
    height: 531px;width:90%
    z-index: 58;
    position: absolute;
    top: +53px;
}
#triangleright {
    height: 531px;width:90%
    z-index: 59;
    position: absolute;
    top: +53px;
}

Comment: still gone, that didn't change a thing, the triangles just aren't showing up at all. The way I originally had it both of them were showing up but the right triangle just wasn't fixed to the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Revised Answer (previous answer removed for clarity's sake):

Looking closer at the leaderbe.com page you referenced in your comment below, I noticed that the HTML structure of the divs was quite different than what you had.  You need to put the triangleright div inside the triangleleft div and use styles like follows:

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uKrNT/2/

```
<div id="wrapper"> <div id="Layer-57">layer 57</div> </div>

<div id="triangleleft">
     <div id="triangleright">
   </div>
 </div>


#triangleleft{
 width:100%;
 height:531px;
 z-index:58;
 position:absolute;
 top:+53px;
 float:left;
 background:red url(http://www.leaderbe.com/images/diamond-left.png)no-repeat;
 margin-left:0px;
    overflow:visible;
    opacity:.5;

}

 #triangleright{
 width:100%;
 height:531px;
 z-index:59;
 float:right;
 background:blue url(http://www.leaderbe.com/images/diamond-right.png)no-repeat;
 margin-right:0px;
    opacity: .5;
    overflow:visible;
}


#wrapper { height:100%; position: relative; }
#Layer-57 { position: relative; height:529px; background:#3b96a9 url(layer-57.jpg) top center no-repeat; top:-529px; overflow-x: hidden; z-index: 57; }
```

Comment: That fixed part of the problem. it put the right triangle on the right side but when I re-size my browser it doesn't stick to the right. That's why I was floating them. I noticed what you did with the 50% width and when I change that to 100% it screws up again. Let me explain. I want each triangle to be fixed to the appropriate side of the browser. When you re-size the browser each triangle moves with it and they can overlap. I have tried everything and i'm just getting stumped. Thanks for giving me a hand on this.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your problem a bit better now.  I'm adding a revised .css snippet for you to try (I also updated my jsfiddle with the revision).

Comment: That just made the problem like it was originally, here this is a website that has the effect I'm looking for. I just can't seem to get mine right. (my triangles aren't the same and I only have 2 but this is what i'm getting at) http://www.leaderbe.com/

Comment: I don't see anything on that example page that is tied to the right. Sorry, wanted to try to help you but I guess I don't correctly the situation.

Comment: also here is the code for my header image that I think is screwing this up       (#wrapper {
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
 }



#Layer-57 {
  position: relative;
 height:529px; background:#3b96a9 url(layer-57.jpg) top center no-repeat; 
 top:-529px;
 overflow-x: hidden; 
  z-index: 57;
})                              ( <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="Layer-57"></div>
</div>)

Comment: the triangle that is over the map image, the one that is partially transparent is what to look at. resize your browser and you'll see what i'm talking about.

Comment: Ok, I've edited your header image code into the question above so other people can find it more easily and have more info to go on.

Comment: didn't fix it it just caused the same problem as for.